# problem with import assets as sprite from illustrator

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello guys I have problem when import images from illustrator I need import image contain pieces of shapes but when export layers from illustrator and import it in unity I found myself need arrange the image again to make my image again like illustrator? I hope find solution I attach 2 image for my problem to make my issue clear to fourm :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually layers in Illustrator are cropped to there content ... so yes these are your layers in Illustrator ;) You could try to raster your forms and copy them into new complete layers so they are expanded to fill the entire area

Comment: Can't you select all and right click 'export as single asset'?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as a sprite that is both a single piece and separate pieces. Either it's going to be a single, whole image, or you have to arrange them yourself. --- The shape of the pieces seems to be uniform, so it might be a good idea to have multiple instances of a single sprite anyways. --- Just have an empty object as an overall parent, an empty object as parent for each piece as a rotation root, and the piece itself with a position offset. Rotate the rotation roots to get the circle. Scale and/or offset position of the sprites to make circle size and sprites touch.

Comment: thanks Thomas Byy I don't want export it as single asset I need every piece as a single in unity but in the same time I need it arranged like circle shape like it in illustrator

Comment: Hi XenoRo if I will arrange it manually it will be very boring and I think this not efficient I need way to export it from illustrator as one layer and separate  it in unity as single pieces